# Limit of integral of the expontial function to a negative power

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{2}e^{-nx^2}dx=0$$ for $a>0$. What can be concluded when $a=0$?

---

I've thinking about a posible solution, but the only idea that came to my mind is to split it in cases:

1. If $0<a<2$
2. If $a\geq 2$. In this case, I would end up with $$\int_{a}^{2}e^{-nx^2}dx=-\int_{2}^{a}e^{-nx^2}dx$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E%28infty%29+e%5E%28-nx%5E2%29

Comment: Enforce the substitution $x\mapsto x/\sqrt{n}$ to find that $$\int_a^2 e^{-nx^2}\,dx=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\int_{a\sqrt{n}}^{2\sqrt{n}}e^{-x^2}\,dx$$And now you can finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will make use of $e^{-x}\le x^{-1}$ for $x>0.$
Assume $0<a<2.$ The function $e^{-nx^2} $ is decreasing so the integral is bounded above by $2e^{-na^2}=2(e^{-a^2})^n.$ For $a=0$ the integral is bounded above by $a+2(e^{-a^2})^n$ for any $a>0$  Taking $a=n^{-1/4}$ gives the bound $$n^{-1/4} +2e^{-n^{1/2}}\le n^{-1/4}+2n^{-1/2}$$

For $ a>2$  the absolute value of the integral is bounded above by $$(a-2)(e^{-4a^2})^n\le a(4a^2)^{-n}< {1\over 16^{n-1}}$$